# Display a list in its 'raw' ./2 format

Tags: list, prolog

Is it possible to display a Prolog list in its ./2 format, e.g.

for the list:

```
| ?- L=[a,b,c].
L = [a,b,c] ? 
yes
```

Is there a means to display:

```
L = .(a, .(b, .(c, []))).
```

Comment: Check out `write_canonical/1` in any ISO-conforming system! `write_canonical/1` is very useful every time you are in doubt about the exact form of terms you are reasoning about. Example with SICStus Prolog:  `?- write_canonical([a,b,c]).`, yieding: `'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[])))`. Very valuable predicate also for data exchange, intended to yield a truly canonical representation that is easy to parse.

Comment: L=[a,b,c], write_canonical(L). worked a treat! I am using sicstus at the moment, sometimes swi at home. I wonder if there are any other means to achieve the same end?

Comment: `write_canonical/1` is the standard and best way to do it. You can of course also implement this yourself, using term inspection and decomposition with `arg/3`, `=../2` etc.

Comment: You can also say  `write_term(L,  [quoted(true), ignore_ops(true)]).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, `write_canonical(List)` or `?- write_term(List, [quoted(true), ignore_ops(true)])`, as pointed out in the comments. Since SWI-Prolog decided to [do things differently](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-lists), this is not good enough:

```
?- write_canonical([a]).
[a]
true.

?- write_term([a], [quoted(true), ignore_ops(true)]).
[a]
true.

?- write_term([a], [dotlists(true)]).
.(a,[])
true.
```

See the [documentation on `write_term/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=write_term/2), pay attention to the options `brace_terms(Bool)` and `dotlists(Bool)`. But beware: if you start SWI-Prolog 7 normally, the `./2` is not the list functor any more!

```
?- L = .(a, []).
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `a' (an atom) % WHAT?

?- L = '[|]'(a, []).
L = [a].
```

If you start it with `swipl --traditional`, things are back to normal, sort of:

```
$ swipl --traditional
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.4-32-g9311e51)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- L = .(a, []).
L = [a].
```

You still cannot use `write_canonical(List)` or `write_term(List, [quoted(true), ignore_ops(true)])`.

Read the linked section of the SWI-Prolog documentation for details and rationale. As an advice, if you decide to use SWI-Prolog stick to SWI-Prolog 7 with the defaults and only use `write_term(List, [dotlists(true)])` if you need to communicate with another Prolog implementation. The usual list notation, `[a, b, ...]` should be good enough in most conventional situations.