# How to use SWI-Prolog ./2 function?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Need example using SWI-Prolog [./2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f((%27.%27)/2)).

The signature is

```
.(+Int,[])
```

Also if there is a name for this operator it would be nice to know. Searching for '.' is senseless.

The closest to a name is from SWI documentation section F.3 [Arithmetic Functions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=funcsummary)

```
List of one character: character code
```

What I tried

```
?- X is .(97,[]).
```

results in

```
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `97' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(type_error(dict,97),_5812))
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Also tried

```
?- X is .(97,['a']).
```

with same result.

Comment: `'.'` is the functor that defines lists. So `.(H, T)` is equivalent to `[H | T]`. `X is .(97, ['a'])` is like writing `X is [97, 'a']` which will, of course, fail since `[97, 'a']` is not an arithmetic expression, a single valid number, or a single character code. The linked documentation says,  *Arithmetic evaluation also translates a string object (see section 5.2) of **one** character length into the character code for that character.* That means you can do `X is .(97, [])` or equivalently, `X is [97]`.

Comment: I tried `X is .(97, []).` before posting and that gave `ERROR: Type error: "dict" expected, found "97" (an integer)`

Comment: Yes, in SWI it will do that because in SWI it also uses the `'.'` for [dictionaries](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts). In the context of `X is .(97, [])` it's thinking of it that way. In GNU Prolog that doesn't happen (I tried in in GNU when I wrote my first comment). In SWI you can do `X is [97]`. SWI has introduced the `[|]` notation to replace the `'.'` for list formation. So you can write, `X is '[|]'(97, []).`. They should explain `[|]/2` in the doc you linked, but they don't.

Comment: Of intereset: [5.1 Lists are special](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-lists)

Comment: Of interest: [ERROR: Type error: "dict" expected, found "c" (an atom)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swi-prolog/NBphQZ8QHew)

Comment: Of interest: [Converting to dot notation in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44112074/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Display a list in its 'raw' ./2 format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31939658/1243762)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard Prolog, the `'.'` functor is the actual list term functor. Specifically, `[H|T]` is equivalent to `'.'(H, T)`. If you run GNU Prolog, for example, you will get this:

```
| ?- write_canonical([H|T]).
'.'(_23,_24)

yes
| ?- X = .(H,T).

X = [H|T]

yes
| ?-
```

The `is/2` operator will allow you to read the character code directly from a list consisting of a single character code. So the following works in Prolog:

```
| ?- X is [97].

X = 97

yes
| ?- X is .(97,[]).

X = 97

yes
```

Where it starts to get interesting is that, in SWI Prolog, they've introduced [dictionaries](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts) that rely on the `'.'` as a means of designating dictionary keys. This creates a conflict with the `'.'` functor being used as a list functor. This is explained in the link on dictionaries. Thus, when you attempt to use the `'.'` functor for a list, you get something like this:

```
1 ?- X is [97].
X = 97.

2 ?- X is .(97, []).
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `97' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(type_error(dict,97),_5184))
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(97,[],_5224) at /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.4.2/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.

3 ?- X = .(H,T).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(instantiation_error,_6914))
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(_6944,_6946,_6948) at /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.4.2/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

SWI has, therefore, defined another functor, `[|]`, to serve the purpose that `'.'` traditionally served, which is the list functor.

```
4 ?- X is '[|]'(97, []).
X = 97.

5 ?- X = '[|]'(H, T).
X = [H|T].

6 ?-
```

Oddly, you might think then that this would happen:

```
7 ?- write_canonical([H|T]).
'[|]'(_, _)
```

However, what happens is this:

```
7 ?- write_canonical([H|T]).
[_|_]
true.
```

So to SWI Prolog, the list representation `[H|T]` is already the canonical representation of the list.

Answer (score 4):

The arithmetic function `'.'/2` maps 
lists holding a single *character* **or** *character code* (terms like `[C]` or `'.'(C,[])`) to the corresponding character *code*.

The particular irratic behavior that you were observing is SWI-Prolog specific.
You can disable the non-standard SWI-Prolog "extensions" (like dicts) by adding the command-line argument `--traditional`, like so:

```
$ swipl --traditional
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.0.0) [...]

?- C = 97, V is [C].
C = 97, V = 97.

?- C = 0'a, V is [C].
C = 97, V = 97.

?- C = a, V is [C].
C = a, V = 97.
```

This also works with string literals:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
?- Str = "a", Str = [C], V is Str.
Str = [97], C = 97, V = 97.

:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
?- Str = "a", Str = [C], V is Str.
Str = [a], C = a, V = 97.
```

Comment: @false. Clumsy me. Back to 1*1 . Lucky me.

Comment: @false. Here I am at 1^2... I don't quite get what setting the flag`double_quotes` to `chars` is going to buy me with `is`. (same as with `atom`)

Comment: What it is going to buy you: Readability. And,  `97 is [a]`