# Prolog - list definition with dot

Tags: list, prolog, definition

I am reading the following [book](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse38) and it mentions the following definition of list (example):

```
?-  .(a,[])  ==  [a].
```

returns

```
yes
```

I tried it with SWI-Prolog and it returned error. What is analog of this expression in SWI-Prolog? Why does it throw error?

Comment: Perhaps unfortunately, SWI Prolog has commandeered the `.` operator for defining [dictionary operations](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts). Thus the error, *Type error: `dict' expected...*. What you're trying will work in, for example, GNU Prolog and several others.

Comment: The question is different the the answer is the same, so it is a duplicate of [How to use SWI-Prolog ./2 function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246704/1243762)

Comment: Frankly, the operator isn't that useful compared to the dictionary stuff (though I haven't used it much yet myself). It's just unfortunate that decades of Prolog books refer to this.

Comment: I agree, @DanielLyons. I guess I suggested "unfortunate" because it creates a bit of confusion initially on this particular "canonical list form" issue. But ultimately, the dictionary is very useful.

Comment: @lurker You gave all of the details in your answer to the original question that I marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks for catching that. :)