# Specific term for "IS" function

Tags: terminology

Is there a specific term for addressing a function that returns a bool.

E.g Getters and Setters

```
function GetSomething();
function SetSomething(value);
```

But what about this:

```
function IsProduction();
```

It's clearly a more specific "Getter" and I feel as if it warrants a different category.

This is obviously a hard question to Google search, so apologies if it's been answered before.

Comment: I don't feel I should post this as an answer, since I don't have any source, but: as you acknowledge, `IsProduction()` is a *getter*, and is completely equivalent to `GetProduction()`. I don't think it deserves a name per se, I think it would be even confusing: if it is conceptually the same of thing A, and serves the sames purpose of thing A, it should be called A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a specific term for addressing a function that returns a bool.

Since a bool returns only true or false, this is known as a [Predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))

---

TL;DR

> This is obviously a hard question to Google search, so apologies if it's been answered before.

That is easier than [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243643/how-to-use-swi-prolog-2-function) for the predicate named `.`

Another hard one to search for is `;`. When you parse code `;` can actually be considered an operator that joins two statements.