# Why do these two prolog sentences have different outputs?

Tags: prolog

I've recently started learning Prolog and there's something that I don't understand.

Why do these two sentences gives different outputs?
I understand that everything at the left of an [ | ] expression must be the head of the list and at the right side we've the tail of the list.
I suspect it must be trivial but at the end I don't get why as in the first case the second one doesn't unify both parts as one single list.

```
?- X = [2|[1]].
   X = [2,1].

?- X = [[1]|2].
   X = [[1]|2].
```

Comment: Why do you expect these to have the same output?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir that's such a wonderful and amazing question I don't usually ask myself. I was seeing it like I was separating in both cases the head and the tail of a unique list and it didn't matter if I was putting the brackets before or after the "|" separator. After asking myself your question I supose what's actually happening is that in both cases I'm creating a list, in the first case pointing that the number "2" is the head of the list and in the second case that the list [1] is the head of the list. Such a dumb confusion, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thesecond one is not a list, or at least not what the "Prolog community" considers a list.

If we take a look at what you wrote, the first expression can be seen as something similar to:

```
+-------+
|  cons |
+---+---+  +-------+
| o | o--->|  cons |
+-|-+---+  +---+---+
  v        | o | o---> nil
  2        +-|-+---+
             v
             1
```

So this is a list: you basically construct a "cons", with as *head* 2, and as tail another list. Note that the head of the list is an element, whereas the tail of the list, is a list with the remaining elements.

In your second example, you probably made a typo, probably you have written:

```
?- X = [[1]|2].
X = [[1]|2].
```

In that case the "list" looks like:

```
+-------+
|  cons |
+---+---+
| o | o---> 2
+-|-+---+
  v        
+-------+
|  cons |
+---+---+
| o | o---> []
+-|-+---+
  v
  1
```

Note that this is not really a list: the head of the cons, is an element, and of course such element can be a list (since we can construct lists of lists, etc.), but the tail here, is simply an element.

This means that one can *not* apply syntactical sugar, and thus replace this with something like `[1,2]`. Note that `[1]` is actually syntactical sugar for `[1|[]]`, and `[2,1]` is syntactical sugar for `[2|[1|[]]]` (as wee see in the first image). But `[[1]|2]` has no such syntactical sugar equivalent.

Most Prolog interpreters allow you to write lists in a canonical way, for example in GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- write_canonical([1]).
'.'(1,[])

(1 ms) yes
| ?- write_canonical([1,2]).
'.'(1,'.'(2,[]))

(1 ms) yes
| ?- write_canonical([[1]|2]).
'.'('.'(1,[]),2)

yes
```

Here we se thus that the "cons" function is the dot `'.'` that is a functor).

Comment: Don't you hate it when the op deletes the question with your answer before without giving you an upvote?

Comment: @GuyCoder: it was in the opposite order: delete, undelete, answer :), but yeah, *Synchronizität* can be hard :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually it was more like: read your comment,  find out i'm such a dumbass, delete, feel like I shouldn't be that hard on myself, undelete, thanks for the comment, then read your answer and understand it perfectly. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: You should add the use of [write_canonical/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write_canonical/1) into your answer but use the GNU Prolog version since it uses ./2 and SWI-Prolog uses [|] instead. And I only know about the weird way SWI-Prolog does it by learning it the hard [way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49243643/1243762)

Comment: @GuyCoder: yes, that was actually the reason why I wanted to stick with something generic as "cons". Cons itself is not the functor, but it thus makes abstraction of the exact details on how the interpreter does this. Edited.